# LinqToSql giving 'Specified cast is not valid'

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I'm running a stored procedure through L2S and it's returning 'Specified cast is not valid'. The stored proc is returning data when ran manually and when I step thru it, everything is fine until it tries to create the row object in "foreach (var row in result)".

```
var q = new db();
var result = q.GetNearbyLocations(latitude, longitude,searchDistance);
foreach (var row in result)
   {
      var c = new Clinic()
                {
                   Name = row.CLINIC_NAME.Trim(),
                   Address1 = row.DRADR1.Trim()...
```

Ideas?

Comment: What are the data types of Clinic.Name, Clinic.Address1, row.CLINIC_NAME, and row.DRADR1?

Comment: I found this link invaluable... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is usually caused by a data type mismatch, e.g. if the stored procedure returns a int and that is mapped to a string, or if the stored proc return a varchar(1) and that is mapped to a System.Char.

Comment: The sproc dynamically creates a string variable and executes it. Linq doesn't like this. In order for Linq to read the return types in correctly, I have to comment it out and put in an equivalent sql statement. Somehow this wasn't happening properly as in the designer.cs, the return type was an int, rather that a recordset. I changed the sproc, reimported and change the sproc back to executing the string variable. All is happy now. 

Thanks All!

Answer (score 1):

Your sporc isn't actually invoked until a `foreach` statement is executed. Therefore, ensure that LINQ to SQL can correctly map data returned from the sproc to your objects.